# Get all namespace with prefix from xml

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I get all xmlns from xml? Using XSLT.
For example I have xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cult:ProjectDocCoordination xmlns:smev="http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/request/rev111111" xmlns:cult="urn://x-artefacts-it-ru/dob/state-services/cult/ProjectDocCoordination/1.0" xmlns:commons="urn://x-artefacts-it-ru/dob/state-services/cult/commons/1.0">
    <cult:Person>
        <commons:FamilyName>Иванов</commons:FamilyName>
        <commons:FirstName>Иван</commons:FirstName>
        <commons:Patronymic>Иванович</commons:Patronymic>
        <cult:OGRNIP>300000000000000</cult:OGRNIP>
        <cult:Phone>9212345678</cult:Phone>
        <cult:Email>test@mail.ru</cult:Email>
        <cult:Address>Address</cult:Address>
    </cult:Person>
    <cult:ObjectRegion>ObjectRegion</cult:ObjectRegion>
    <cult:ObjectName>ObjectName</cult:ObjectName>
    <cult:ScientificDesignDeveloperInfo>
        <cult:ProjectDocName>ProjectDocName</cult:ProjectDocName>
        <cult:ProjectDocComposition>ProjectDocComposition</cult:ProjectDocComposition>
        <cult:DeveloperLegalInfo>
            <cult:DeveloperULName>ООО Удача</cult:DeveloperULName>
            <cult:DeveloperULOPF>DeveloperULOPF</cult:DeveloperULOPF>
            <cult:Address>Address</cult:Address>
        </cult:DeveloperLegalInfo>
    </cult:ScientificDesignDeveloperInfo>
    <cult:LicenseInfo>
        <cult:Number>001877</cult:Number>
        <cult:Date>2014-06-06</cult:Date>
    </cult:LicenseInfo>
    <test:JobInfo xmlns:test="http://test.test.com">
        <test:Number>67800</test:Number>
        <test:Date>2014-08-06</test:Date>
        <test:AgentName>Иванов Иван Иванович</test:AgentName>
        <test:Phone>9212345678</test:Phone>
    </test:JobInfo>
    <cult:NoChangedCharacteristics>true</cult:NoChangedCharacteristics>
    <cult:CapitalReconstruction>true</cult:CapitalReconstruction>
    <cult:ResultInfo>Выдать лично на руки</cult:ResultInfo>
    <cult:DocInfo>
        <cult:Document1>
            <smev:AppliedDocument smev:ID="ID_1">
                <smev:CodeDocument>String</smev:CodeDocument>
                <smev:Name>1.txt</smev:Name>
                <smev:Number>1</smev:Number>
                <smev:URL>1.txt</smev:URL>
                <smev:Type>text/plain</smev:Type>
                <smev:DigestValue>UjBsR09EbGhjZ0dTQUxNQUFBUUNBRU1tQ1p0dU1GUXhEUzhi</smev:DigestValue>
            </smev:AppliedDocument>
        </cult:Document1>
    </cult:DocInfo>
</cult:ProjectDocCoordination>
```

I want to get something this(separator = $):

```
xmlns:smev="http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/request/rev111111"$xmlns:cult="urn://x-artefacts-it-ru/dob/state-services/cult/ProjectDocCoordination/1.0"$xmlns:commons="urn://x-artefacts-it-ru/dob/state-services/cult/commons/1.0"$xmlns:test="http://test.test.com"
```

Or this(without "xmlns:"):

```
smev="http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/request/rev111111"$cult="urn://x-artefacts-it-ru/dob/state-services/cult/ProjectDocCoordination/1.0"$commons="urn://x-artefacts-it-ru/dob/state-services/cult/commons/1.0"$test="http://test.test.com"
```

Comment: Which version of XSLT do you use? Unique namespace informations are found with `//namespace::*[not(. = ../../namespace::*) and not(. = 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace')]` in XPath 1.0 or `distinct-values(//namespace::*[not(. = 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace')])` in XPath 2.0. Read up on the namespace axis: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#namespace-nodes

Comment: I use 2.0 version. if I use "distinct-values(//namespace::*[not(. = 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace')])", then I get all difference NS, but without prefix. how can I get prefix for each NS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `distinct-values()` here, because then you get only the URI values and lose the prefixes. Also, there could be two or more prefixes linked to the same URI - or vice-versa.

Try it this way instead:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//namespace::*[not(name()='xml')]" group-by="concat(name(), '|', .)">
        <xsl:text>xmlns:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:text>="</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>"&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
xmlns:smev="http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/request/rev111111"
xmlns:cult="urn://x-artefacts-it-ru/dob/state-services/cult/ProjectDocCoordination/1.0"
xmlns:commons="urn://x-artefacts-it-ru/dob/state-services/cult/commons/1.0"
xmlns:test="http://test.test.com"
```

Pick your own delimiters as required.